# React simple maps load topo-json parse issue

Tags: json, reactjs

I am following the guide for react-simple-maps npm documentation to get a map up and running so I can have a play with it.

The code sample I am using is from the usage section at the following link:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-maps#Geographies-component

The issue I have is with the topojson file loading:

```
 <Geographies geographyUrl={ "/path/to/your/topojson-map-file.json" }>
```

When trying to load the topojson file I seem to keep getting:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

error whenever it attempts to load the file.

It happens at Geographies.js line 52 at the following statement:

```
request.open("GET", geographyUrl, true);
```

I am using one of the topojson files that it uses in the example from their GitHub page so the JSON is correct.

Within my React application I have the topojson file located at:

```
src/static/topo-data.json
```

I have tried different ways of loading the JSON file into the component page such as importing it:

```
import data from '../../static/topo-data.json'
```

I used create-react-app to create the application and as far as I am aware Json-loader comes as default.

I have also just put the full path into the geographyUrl section with no luck.

When I have debugged the code to look at the response.responseText it isn't the JSON file it is just the index.html file of my own application. I assume it is the way I am loading the file is incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loading topojson files using `geographyUrl` in the create-react-app environment, you have to place it in the public folder. If you place world-50m.json directly in public (`./public/world-50m.json`), this should do the trick:

```
// in ./src/App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'

import {
  ComposableMap,
  ZoomableGroup,
  Geographies,
  Geography,
} from "react-simple-maps"

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ComposableMap>
          <ZoomableGroup>
            <Geographies geographyUrl="/world-50m.json">
              {(geographies, projection) =>
                geographies.map((geography, i) =>
                  <Geography
                    key={geography.id}
                    geography={geography}
                    projection={projection}
                  />
                )
              }
            </Geographies>
          </ZoomableGroup>
        </ComposableMap>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Alternatively, if you want to load the topojson via json import, you can use `topojson-client` to convert it and then feed it directly to `geographyPaths` instead of `geographyUrl`. You can follow the approach from here:

https://github.com/zcreativelabs/react-simple-maps/blob/master/examples/custom-json-geographyPaths/pages/index.js

but instead just use json import, instead of loading the topojson using axios.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I moved it to the public folder and used the suggested pathing and it worked. Much appreciated